# How to access docker from ubuntu on wsl-2 on windows 10

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I installed docker on my windows 10 pro several weeks ago. And now installed wsl-2 and ubuntu on windows. When I started ubuntu on windows, I can not access the docker from ubuntu shell. So is this possible? Or should I install docker on ubuntu?

Comment: We would access docker from windows (cmd or powershell9. We can run docker with the WLS2 backend (see [the official docker documentatiion](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/) for details).

Comment: There is no need to `apt-get install docker`. Open Docker Desktop and: Settings(gear icon), Resources, WSL Integration. Check if your wsl distro has docker enabled.